# Javascript accordion with anchors for joomla

Tags: extensions, javascript

I do not know javascript and scss very well so I am struggling with creating an accordion for a page.
I would like two options:

1. When one panel is opened, the other collapses.
2. Every heading of a panel has an anchor, and when i go to the link [www.example.com#heading1](http://www.example.com#heading1), the page scrolls to the heading1 and opens its section.

It used to work in this [extension](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mooaccordion/), but the anchors disappeared suddenly (i've checked in Chrome and Ff).

For now i found in internet this accordion:

```
<div class="accordion-container">
  <div class="ac">
    <h2 class="ac-q" tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
    <div class="ac-a">
      <p>Nulla et sodales nisl. Nam auctor quis odio eu congue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ac">
    <h2 class="ac-q" tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
    <div class="ac-a">
      <p>Nulla et sodales nisl. Nam auctor quis odio eu congue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ac">
    <h2 class="ac-q" tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
    <div class="ac-a">
      <p>Nulla et sodales nisl. Nam auctor quis odio eu congue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  

<script>
"use strict";
! function (i)
{
  function u(o, l)
  {
    var c = this,
      t = {
        init: function ()
        {
          if (Array.isArray(o)) return o.length && o.map(function (e)
          {
            return new u(e, l)
          }), !1;
          this.options = h(
          {
            duration: 600,
            itemNumber: 0,
            aria: !0,
            closeOthers: !0,
            showItem: !1,
            elementClass: "ac",
            questionClass: "ac-q",
            answerClass: "ac-a",
            targetClass: "ac-target",
            onToggle: function () {}
          }, l), this.container = document.querySelector(o), this.elements = this.container.querySelectorAll("." + this.options.elementClass);
          var e = this.options,
            t = e.aria,
            n = e.showItem,
            i = e.itemNumber;
          t && this.container.setAttribute("role", "tablist");
          for (var s = 0; s < this.elements.length; s++)
          {
            var r = this.elements[s];
            r.classList.add("js-enabled"), this.hideElement(r), this.setTransition(r), this.generateID(r), t && this.setARIA(r)
          }
          if (n)
          {
            var a = this.elements[0];
            "number" == typeof i && i < this.elements.length && (a = this.elements[i]), this.toggleElement(a, !1)
          }
          c.attachEvents()
        },
        setTransition: function (e)
        {
          var t = this.options,
            n = t.duration,
            i = t.answerClass,
            s = e.querySelector("." + i),
            r = a("transition");
          s.style[r] = n + "ms"
        },
        generateID: function (e)
        {
          e.setAttribute("id", "ac-".concat(s)), s++
        },
        setARIA: function (e)
        {
          var t = this.options,
            n = t.questionClass,
            i = t.answerClass,
            s = e.querySelector("." + n),
            r = e.querySelector("." + i);
          s.setAttribute("role", "tab"), s.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false"), r.setAttribute("role", "tabpanel")
        },
        updateARIA: function (e, t)
        {
          var n = this.options.questionClass;
          e.querySelector("." + n).setAttribute("aria-expanded", t)
        },
        callSpecificElement: function (e)
        {
          for (var t = e.target, n = this.options, i = n.questionClass, s = n.targetClass, r = n.closeOthers, a = 0; a < this.elements.length; a++)
            if (this.elements[a].contains(t))
            {
              (t.className.match(i) || t.className.match(s)) && (e.preventDefault(), r && this.closeAllElements(a), this.toggleElement(this.elements[a]));
              break
            }
        },
        hideElement: function (e)
        {
          var t = this.options.answerClass;
          e.querySelector("." + t).style.height = 0
        },
        toggleElement: function (e, t)
        {
          var n, i = !(1 < arguments.length && void 0 !== t) || t,
            s = this.options,
            r = s.answerClass,
            a = s.aria,
            o = s.onToggle,
            l = e.querySelector("." + r),
            c = l.scrollHeight;
          e.classList.toggle("is-active"), i || (l.style.height = "auto"), 0 < parseInt(l.style.height) ? (n = !1, requestAnimationFrame(function ()
          {
            l.style.height = 0
          })) : (n = !0, requestAnimationFrame(function ()
          {
            l.style.height = c + "px"
          })), a && this.updateARIA(e, n), i && o(e, this.elements)
        },
        closeAllElements: function (e)
        {
          for (var t = this.options.aria, n = this.elements.length, i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (i != e)
            {
              var s = this.elements[i];
              s.classList.contains("is-active") && s.classList.remove("is-active"), t && this.updateARIA(s, !1), this.hideElement(s)
            }
        },
        resizeHandler: function ()
        {
          for (var e, t, n = this.options, i = n.elementClass, s = n.answerClass, r = this.container.querySelectorAll("." + i + ".is-active"), a = 0; a < r.length; a++) t = r[a].querySelector("." + s), requestAnimationFrame(function ()
          {
            t.style.height = "auto", e = t.offsetHeight, requestAnimationFrame(function ()
            {
              t.style.height = e + "px"
            })
          })
        },
        clickHandler: function (e)
        {
          this.callSpecificElement(e)
        },
        keydownHandler: function (e)
        {
          13 === e.keyCode && this.callSpecificElement(e)
        }
      };
    this.attachEvents = function ()
    {
      var e = t;
      e.clickHandler = e.clickHandler.bind(e), e.keydownHandler = e.keydownHandler.bind(e), e.resizeHandler = e.resizeHandler.bind(e), e.container.addEventListener("click", e.clickHandler), e.container.addEventListener("keydown", e.keydownHandler), i.addEventListener("resize", e.resizeHandler)
    }, this.detachEvents = function ()
    {
      var e = t;
      e.container.removeEventListener("click", e.clickHandler), e.container.removeEventListener("keydown", e.keydownHandler), i.removeEventListener("resize", e.resizeHandler)
    };
    var a = function (e)
      {
        return "string" == typeof document.documentElement.style[e] ? e : (e = n(e), e = "webkit".concat(e))
      },
      n = function (e)
      {
        return e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1)
      },
      h = function (e, t)
      {
        for (var n in t) e[n] = t[n];
        return e
      };
    i.requestAnimationFrame = i.requestAnimationFrame || i.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || function (e)
    {
      i.setTimeout(e, 1e3 / 60)
    }, t.init()
  }
  var s = 0;
  "undefined" != typeof module && void 0 !== module.exports ? module.exports = u : i.Accordion = u
}(window);

</script>    

<script>
  new Accordion('.accordion-container'); 
</script>
```

I can insert in in an article and it works. But nothing happens when I try to add an anchor. I suppose it requires additional javascript.

I have found an answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447803/open-a-specific-accordion-panel-with-an-external-anchor-link/50448207), but I still do not see anchors working when i run it locally, neither i can insert it into joomla article properly.

I also tried many of [these](https://freefrontend.com/css-accordions/) accordions. But only [this one](https://codepen.io/JeremyWink/pen/PoYdrLV?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=65841cbae77bb00196e4f6f62a0c45d464066e19-1595238428-0-AQ5l1jjuACZ2CSYO1ZZzV7CrgDPd9dt15JsBqDw8TK9XbbVjYPFJUxmeUQ5RV2gFOkKZ2LONu4r2aVKbdj6l3ELQj5eokjuXc8A2-qCkdVcEyUPe5M1S6O1sNyqSwSh9FF1PB3Nky3gzbBez1vcd8Utffeti0iwf_YbXjgwvFTuI5Nk_OXYnKXAVujPjVE8_iVK4wtYgglOfbHAQNP-pjEztR3c-xN9WkMM-DO0UJkk9m8KrT2h6WAIqMPrH7mMkBYaEHVloLBdIMRoVB--b1NZWYxokDzBQLK_I782lGJ4zcLOg4CvXdyLHo6ykOr4KCj5r98bH56PqBP6l5dIHFqsZ-XUx_iGUDiCVrRlx97em) has anchors. But it doesn't work, when I try to edit the text or add fields.

I would appreciate any help very much, or some links to guides, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take our [tour].  (This question was originally posted on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62969870/2943403).)

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately the Javascript is rather hard to read. It looks like it has been minified and then beautified, so the variable names aren't very descriptive, e.g `var a = ...`. Do you have the original? The extension you linked to in your question is rather old. It's based on Mootools which is being phased out in Joomla and completely removed in Joomla 4.

Comment: @Lodder, Finally found the original - https://github.com/michu2k/Accordion/blob/master/dist/accordion.js I'd be grateful, if you could help with improving this accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this does't directly answer your question have you looked at the Sliders plugin from Regular Labs (https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sliders)?

It does what you need with # linking.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine. But there is still a little problem: when you follow the link and the page scrolls to the slider and opens it, the header is not shown, it is higher. I tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534661/make-anchor-link-go-some-pixels-above-where-its-linked-to) solution, but didn't succeed, do you think it's possible? Maybe I should post this question separately.

Comment: There is a setting for "scroll offset" which will fix this. I believe it's a pro feature only.